# ReactJS Application is not working in old chrome 27 version

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created fresh ReactJS project using create-react-app,
used node Version : 12.22.12,
To make compactable for older version browser I have used polyfill core-js,
after using polyfill now it working in chrome 31 version onwards. It is not working in chrome 27 to 30. Getting error:- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
`package.json file`

```
    {
      "name": "xyz",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "core-js": "^3.25.0",
        "grommet": "^2.25.0",
        "grommet-controls": "^3.0.2",
        "grommet-icons": "^4.7.0",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
        "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
          "react-app",
          "react-app/jest"
        ]
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "compression-webpack-plugin": "^10.0.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.1",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.5.0"
      }
    }
```

Another method which I have tried

I have created ReactJS project using Webpack,
used node Version : 12.22.12,
This is not working in older version of chrome,
Getting Error:- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
`package.json file`

```
    {
      "name": "xyz",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "webpack serve --mode development",
        "build": "webpack --mode production"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.18.10",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.10",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.2",
        "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
        "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
        "webpack": "^5.74.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.3"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
        "core-js": "^3.25.1",
        "grommet": "^2.25.1",
        "grommet-controls": "^3.0.2",
        "grommet-icons": "^4.7.0",
        "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
        "styled-components": "^5.3.5"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's rather related to `create-react-app`

Please follow [this guide](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/supported-browsers-features/)

The first thing you can do is change `browserlist`, because now you only support the newest browsers with your configuration

```
"browserslist": {
  "production": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "development": [
    "last 1 chrome version",
    "last 1 firefox version",
    "last 1 safari version"
  ]
}
```

But I doubt you can run React on a browser from 2013.

Comment: I tried this.. It is not working for me